# Differential equations whose coefficients are derivatives of a given function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider an ordinary linear differential equation of the form
$$
0=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i g^{(n-i)}(x)f^{(i)}(x)}\tag{*},
$$
where $a_i$ are real numbers, $g$ is a given function, $f$ is the function to be solved for, and the bracketed superscript denotes differentiation.

If $a_i=\binom{n}{i}$, then, by the [General Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule),  $({}^*)$ can be written as
$$
0=\left(g\,f\right)^{(n)}(x),
$$
which implies that
$$
(gf)(x)=p(x)=\text{polynomial of degree $n-1$}
$$
and thus $({}^*)$ has the general solution
$$
f(x) = p(x)/g(x).
$$

> **Question**: For what other choices of coefficients $a_i$ and function $g$ can $({}^*)$ be solved systematically?